# two endpoint within one service host

Tags: wcf, wcf-endpoint

I have 3 projects in a solution as following:

1. **WCF Service Library** *"ServiceLib"*(contract `ICalculator` and its implementation `Calculator1`).
2. **Console Application** *"ServiceHost"* to host WCF Service Library(and another `ICalculator` implementation `Calculator2`);

   add `Calculator1` & `Calculator2` into an instance of `ServiceHost` using method `AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), new WSHttpBinding(), "Calculator1")`,
   `AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), new WSHttpBinding(), "Calculator2")`
3. Add Service Reference to *"ServiceHost"* to my client application(type of **Console Application**);
   an app.config(auto-generated) within this project

> **question** is: How to consume these two Calculators(different logic) from client app side, does it necessary to create two different types of client proxy or other way to do that?

thanks for your hand!

```
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/Calculator" binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ICalculator" contract="Services_BaseAddress.ICalculator"
            name="WSHttpBinding_ICalculator">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/DoubleCalculator" binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ICalculator1" contract="Services_BaseAddress.ICalculator"
            name="WSHttpBinding_ICalculator1">
        </endpoint>
```

Comment: Yes, you will need to create two separate clients. You can't create a client for one service and then use it for a different service.

Comment: @Tim Thanks to help clear my concept confusion. does it not function when a contract implementation done within my service host project, because it makes no difference after I use another endpoint name to create a new client?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - can you clarify your question?

Comment: yes, one serviceHost(`http://localhost:8000/`) adds two serviceEndpoints with the same contract and the same type of binding(WSHttpBinding) but different relative addresses which cause different endpoints(attached above) on my client side, **Question** :can I use these two endpoints name to create two types of client(different behavior)? I'm not sure if I clarify my question thanks so much.

Comment: it seems the bug has been found, one service host can only host one implementation of a contract, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.